# Is it idiomatic to put "nonetheless" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

this comes from "NoSQL ＆ SQL Data Modeling" by Ted Hills.

> The rectangle represents a logical record type. This is not a type in
>   the sense of a generalization/specialization hierarchy. It is a type
>   in the sense that it designates a set. A logical record type is a list
>   of data attributes aggregated together, and it implicitly designates
>   the set of all possible values of those data attributes taken
>   together—the Cartesian product of the data attributes’ types.
>   Sometimes the display of these data attributes is suppressed, and only
>   the name of the entity is visible, but the rectangle represents the
>   data attributes nonetheless

is it idiomatic to put "nonetheless" at the end of a sentence?

Comment: I think he’s asking whether putting it at the end of a sentence is a common practice, not whether the word “nonetheless” is valid or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Nonetheless" [one word] is a valid adverb. It means the same as "nevertheless", or "in spite of what has just been said".

As an adverb it can be used to modify an entire clause or sentence, and, yes, it sounds fine to put "nonetheless" at the end of a sentence. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonetheless) gives two examples of the use of "nonetheless" at the end of a sentence:

> "The hike was difficult, but fun nonetheless."
>
> "Sometimes you can be a real jerk, but I like you nonetheless."